# Customize Menu using Foundation

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sass, zurb-foundation

**NOTE:** I can achieve this behavior using media queries and some Jquery/Javascript but is there any other solution for this using (pure sass and/or css) **ZURB-FOUNDATION** ...

Well let images say

**Current Behavior**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Desire behavior**

For large screen menu is fine for me below are images of smaller and more smaller screens

[image]

[image]

So as soon as (by reducing screen size) if any menu item not adjust in one row then that menu option will go into the icon as shown in above images.

My Question: Is there any way to achieve desire behavior using Foundation - sass and/or css ??

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Anything at all?

Comment: Well I just try a simple foundation menu (that hides all menu options in small screen) ... but for this customization I didn't try anything because I really have no idea about its solution / approach ... If you just give me a good idea that would be fine too ...

Comment: AFAIK, js is the only way

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do this, which is kinda stupid and would be much cleaner with just a js solution.

However, if you want to do a Foundation-only solution, you'll need to structure your header info as such:

```
<ul><li>opt1</li>
    <li>opt2</li>
    <li>opt3</li>
    <li class="hide-for-small">opt4</li>
    <li class="hide-for-medium-down">opt5</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" class="button dropdown hide-for-large-up">icon</a><br>
    <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown">
        <li class="show-for-small">opt4</li>
        <li class="show-for-medium-down">opt5</li>
</ul>
```